# How create right to left tabbox in zk?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, zk

I'm working on a j2ee project using zk framework. I have a tabbox in my `.zul` file but it's left-to-right and the tabs are starting from the left side. How can i change this tabbox to be right-to-left ? (i want the tabs to be started from right side of the tabbox)
I tried too add `direction : rtl` or `text-align : right` in the sclass but it didn't change anything

Comment: did you try to set the align attribute to  end?

Comment: yes i did but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably need to override the tabs default style and reverse direction to right-to-left. you can check this [link](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Style_Guide/ZK_Class_Concept/Zclass) for more information about overriding the style, and this [one](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Style%20Guide/XUL%20Component%20Specification/Tabbox/Default%20%28Horizontal%29) to find out what classes to override.
You can proceed this way:

```
<style>
      .z-tab-text {
        unicode-bidi: bidi-override; 
        direction: rtl; 
       }
</style>
<tabbox id="tabbox" >
    <tabs>
        <tab label="test" style="float:right;"  />

    </tabs>
</tabbox>
```

Comment: i read the links and i changed my css sections but it didn't work. also in these links there is nothing for somethings like `direction` to be `rtl` or `text-align` and somethings like this.

Comment: why don't you try adding the style to the tab?<tab label="test" style="float:right" />

Comment: yeah. i did it. thanks. but the question still stands : why `direction:rtl` doesn't work ? what if i want to write some right-to-left texts in a tab label ?